# There have any process to detect an image is a black&white image or a colored image?

Tags: swift2

I need to detect an image is a color image or black&white image. But don't understand what will be the process or there have any function to detect it. If there have no function to detect it then what will be the process?

Answer (score 0):

Image file has mode, which tells if it is RGB, grayscale or B&W.

I assume you know that and you are trying to examine a RGB image to see if it only has black / white color. In this case you can calculate the histogram of the image in all R/G/B channels, the black and white will have two sharp peaks in all three channels.

Please use a image editing software like GIMP and experiment.